# Can MySQL query include HTML values?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search

REVISED QUESTION:

How can I reference a row of MySQL data while a form is being filled out.  In other words, with my ('Select * FROM... how can I specify the row to pull the fields from without having to process the form to get the PHP fields?

Desired Process 1) User inputs first value, 2) Sidebar MySQL query looks up that value and fills div with data from that row, 3) User continues to fill out form while able to see div filed with MySQL data

ORIGINAL QUESTION:

I am curious if you can include a reference to an HTML input in a MySQL query.

Take the following for an example.

```
('SELECT * FROM MyTableName WHERE MyColumnID="MyHTMLInputValue"');
```

I would like to reference all the fields in the row based on the value of an input field and not sure of how to reference such a query.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean an html input element's value `<input type="text" value="mysqlstring">`?

Comment: define "HTML values". I think I know what you want to do here, and I suggest you don't if that is to read as `WHERE MyColumnID="<b>Hello world</b>"`. HTML is HTML, MySQL is MySQL.

Comment: By values I mean from a hidden value.

Comment: hidden values only get passed "after" the form's been processed, not during. 
Question's a tad unclear here.

Comment: well if you can represent it as text or binary, sure. So, can you?

Comment: Can you show your actual usage? `SELECT * FROM MyTableName WHERE MyColumnID="' . $_GET['injectme'] . '"'`. Would be valid, I don't recommend it.

Comment: But currently I have a javascript which fills in a hidden value as soon as the user clicks to the next field, it is this value that I am wishing to be able to pass to a query.

Comment: Do you know how to use forms and getting the php POST variables?

Comment: Yes, I know how to do that, but the whole reason I passed the variable to the hidden field in the first place is so that my sidebar div can populate the info about that geological time period as the person continues to fill out the form.

Comment: The answer to your revised question is AJAX. http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/

Answer (score 1):

Ajax is the way to go.

This example uses jQuery.

First we need to setup a php script to get our value and search for it, then return our data.

PHP `myPhpScript.php`

```
<?php
 $search_value = $_POST["field1"]; //Get our value from the post.
 //Make sure to do some authentication on the value so that bad values dont get through
 $connection = new mysqli(Stuff here);
 $rows = $connection->query(
 "SELECT * FROM someTable where searchColumn LIKE %".$search_value."%"
 );

 //Now all we need to do is send out our data. Lets use json.
 $out = $rows[0];//Get the first row. NOTE: Make sure to remove any columns that you dont want the client to see.

 echo json_encode($out); //Send the client the data.
?>
```

Javascript `Some script on the page.`

```
var textbox = $("#mySearchBox"); //This is the jQuery object for our text box.
var viewbox = $("#myViewer"); //This is the jQuery object for the div that holds the results

textbox.on("input", function () {
$.ajax({
  url: "myPhpScript.php", //This is the php script that we made above.
  method: "POST", //This set our method to POST.
  data: {field1: textbox.val()}, //set the textbox value to field1
  dataType: "json", //So jquery formats the json into an object.
  success: function (phpDataObject) { //Now its up to you to decide what to do with the data. Example below
    viewbox.html("");//Clear the viewbox.
    viewbox.append("Id: "+phpDataObject["id"]); //Show the id of row that was found.
  }
});
});
```

This code may not work. Just fix whatever syntax errors that show up.

Hope this helps.

Comment if you need any more help.

Comment: I guess I need to do some more reading into the syntax of AJAX and Jquery as I could not get it to work.  Thank you for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

This does not sound like a good idea. Usually you want some separation between your site and database. You could take in "MyHTMLInputValue", process it, then you can complete your query.

```
var myValue = MyHTMLInputValue;
//validate input
('SELECT * FROM MyTableName WHERE MyColumnID="' + myValue + '"')
```

Comment: Why would you generate an sql query in javascript? I hope you are not suggesting sending complete queries from the client to the server.

Comment: `WHERE MyColumnID="' + myValue + '"'` you wanting them to do math here?

Comment: I have not even done anything yet, I am just a student (geophysics) so wasn't sure if this was a possibility.  The ultimate idea behind it was to for example, say someone posts that they are in a certain geological time period, the hidden field would immediately grab that value.  I then wanted to take that hidden field value and reference back to mysql table all the details of that time period.

Comment: @jeroen: I work with C# a lot. JavaScript is not the only language where you can declare a variable with `var`. Not to mention I have no idea whether this is an `int`, `long`, etc.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: string concatenation :)

Comment: @Gavin The question is tagged php / mysql and talks about html, so javascript seems the only language possible in this context. But of course there are other languages you could post code in...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can include any HTML. Below is the example for it:

```
SELECT concat('<b><u><i>',businessname,'</i></u></b>') as businessURL FROM tblbusiness
```